# check date from html5 datepicker with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check the input from an html5 datepicker using java script? I want to know if the date is larger than 01-01-1990.

Comment: And what have you tried yourself ?

Comment: Since you are new to the community, and also this is the first time you have asked a question, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refrain from asking questions like this and make sure you go through the **[tour]** before asking further questions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hst2nuzv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and parse the value with the value of 1990:

```
<input type="date"
       onblur="alert(new Date(this.value) > new Date('01-01-1990'))" />
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/weganuhupu**

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user5673214 You are welcome! `:)`

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this ==>

var d = new Date();
   var myYear = d.getFullYear('01.01.1990');

($('dateField').val().getFullYear()) > myYear ? 'DoSomething' :    'DoSomethingElse'

Comment: `$` will be undefined...